# Adding an identity column while creating athena table

Tags: amazon-athena

I want to create an **athena table** from data stored in **aws-s3**. But in addition I also want an **identity column**. Since **Athena** uses **presto sql engine**, I ran the query written below in **Athena** but it was giving **error code  400** : **invalidrequestexception**. **Athena query** written below :-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `db_name`.`preprocessed` (
id bigint unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_action` string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
`platform` string
`dateval` string
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION <S3-LOCATION>
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Here **S3-LOCATION** is the location of my parquet files where data is stored inside **aws-s3**.
Maybe this is because, **AUTO_INCREMENT** is a problem for **Athena** since **CREATE TABLE** query only creates a **table plan** with the help of **s3 data** stored in **parquet** files instead of loading the data from **s3**. But if there is any way to add an **identity column** along with the **s3 data**, please mention the solution. It will be a lot of help for me here.

Comment: deterministic means returns the same value always when called with the same arguments. Are you sure you need deterministic function depending on non-unique arguments ? UUID imho would be better in such case

Comment: @Tushar Vatsal: can you add a new column into the table having the MD5 / SHA checksum over all colums giving you a column where you can filer distinct values

Comment: You can `ORDER BY` over all columns. This combined with good partitioning column will still execute in parallel. Something like  `row_number() over (PARTITION BY some_good_partitioning_columns ORDER BY other_column_1, other_column_2, ..., other_column_150)`. (To be precise: you don't need to `ORDER BY` on columns that you `PARTITION BY`). Also, `rank()` is a better choice than `row_number()`. With `rank()` equal rows will get the same number assigned, so they will remain equal.

Comment: But ordering by 150 columns, do you think is a good idea performance wise

Comment: Can you please post an example of a file name stored in s3? Does it have some kind the common structure with some timestamp or so?

Comment: "part-00000-349059e1-c81e-4632-b5be-f0b0a455136d-c000.snappy.parquet" : this is an example of a filename stored in s3. No, it does not have.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you don't have any column for performing `order by` clause.
So you can do this by this way using `(select 1)` on order by clause.

```
select row_number() over (partition by col1 order by (select 1)) as Slno....
```

This will give order by to the default value as they are inserted in table.

Comment: `row_number()` without real `order by` may or may not be stable, depending on the implementation. It may work today and break tomorrow.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: this is what OP wants, what will be the alternate in this case.

Comment: Why do you need `order by (select 1)` ? this is completely useless. And this will not give "order by to the default value as they are inserted in table"

Comment: Order by (select 1) will not work and you said it will give number in the order entries are inserted in db. Can  you explain this ?